# Asp.NET Page redirection issue

Tags: asp.net

I have set the `defaultUrl` as

```
<forms loginUrl="Home/Login.aspx" defaultUrl="Items/Default.aspx" name="MySite" timeout="120" slidingExpiration="true" requireSSL="false"/>
```

problem is when i first time login it takes me to the `defualtUrl` page but once i click on the logout button it logs me out, if i log back in again it takes me to `Home/Default.aspx` instead. i am using `FormAuthentication`.
I have tried following settings as well

```
<system.webServer>
    <defaultDocument enabled="true">
      <files>
        <add value="Items/Default.aspx"/>
      </files>
    </defaultDocument>
  </system.webServer>
```

I dont know the reason why its happening. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does `Items/Default.aspx` require the user to be authenticated in order to get access to it? If so, it may be the cause of such behaviour.

You can allow anonymous user access to `Items/Default.aspx` by doing this in your web.config:

```
<location path="Items/Default.aspx">
<system.web>
    <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
    </authorization>
</system.web>
</location>
```

**Update**: This may be a workaround for your issue whilst you find another alternative:

In the `Page_Load` of `Home/Default.aspx` you can check if the user is actually authenticated and redirect them accordingly:

```
if (!this.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    Response.Redirect("Items/Default.aspx");
}
```

I hope this help.

Comment: thanks, I have tried unfortunately it didn't work, i am getting the same behaviour.